# Cannot update webpage using python requests returning error response code 400

Tags: python, json, python-requests, httprequest, confluence-rest-api

I am trying to update an already existing page in the Atlassian confluence page through the Python requests module. I am using the requests.put() method to send the HTTP request to update my page. The page already has the title "Update Status". I am trying to enter one line as the content of the page. The page id and other information that is within the JSON payload has been copied by me directly from the rest/API/content... output of the webpage I am trying to access. Note: I am already able to access information from the webpage through `python requests.get` but I am not able to post information to the webpage.

The method used to access information from the webpage which works:

```
response = requests.get('https://confluence.ai.com/rest/api/content/525424594?expand=body.storage',
                        auth=HTTPBasicAuth('svc-Automation@ai.com', 'AIengineering1@ai')).json()
```

Below is the code I used to update the webpage that is returning error code 400.

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import json

url = "https://confluence.ai.com/rest/api/content/525424594"
payload =  {"id":"525424594","type":"page", "title":"new page-Update Status","space":{"key":"TST"},"body":{"storage":{"value": "<p>This is the updated text for the new page</p>","representation":"storage"}}, "version":{"number":2}}

result = requests.put(url, json=payload, auth=HTTPBasicAuth('svc-Automation@ai.com', 'AIengineering1@ai'))
print (result.content)
```

result.content outputs the below status:

```
{"statusCode":400, "data":{"authorized":true, "valid":false, "allowedInReadOnlyMode":true, "errors can't change an existing page's space.", "args":[]}}], "successful":false}, "message":"Could not update content of type : class com.atlassian.confluence.pages.Page with id 525424594","reason": "Bad Request"}
```

When I go to the link https://confluence.ai.com/rest/api/content/525424594?expand=body.storage I get the rest api content of my page as:

```
{"id":"525424594","type":"page","status":"current","title":"Update Status","space":{"id":152698959,"key":"AIENG","name":"Consumer Solutions (AI) ENG","type":"global","_links":{"webui":"/display/CSSFW","self":"https://confluence.ai.com/rest/api/space/AIENG"},"_expandable":{"metadata":"","icon":"","description":"","homepage":"/rest/api/content/155503904"}},"history":{"latest":true,"createdBy":{"type":"known","username":"Ashish.Joshi@ai.com","userKey":"8a78e5ac71e441c5017250468bbc0259","profilePicture":{"path":"/images/icons/profilepics/default.svg","width":48,"height":48,"isDefault":true},"displayName":"Ashish.Joshi@ai.com","_links":{"self":"https://confluence.ai.com/rest/api/user?key=8a78e5ac71e441c5017250468bbc0259"},"_expandable":{"status":""}},"createdDate":"2021-04-18T00:14:32.732Z","_links":{"self":"https://confluence.ai.com/rest/api/content/525424594/history"},"_expandable":{"lastUpdated":"","previousVersion":"","contributors":"","nextVersion":""}},"version":{"by":{"type":"known","username":"Ashish.Joshi@ai.com","userKey":"8a78e5ac71e441c5017250468bbc0259","profilePicture":{"path":"/images/icons/profilepics/default.svg","width":48,"height":48,"isDefault":true},"displayName":"Ashish.Joshi@ai.com","_links":{"self":"https://confluence.ai.com/rest/api/user?key=8a78e5ac71e441c5017250468bbc0259"},"_expandable":{"status":""}},"when":"2021-04-18T00:16:18.762Z","message":"","number":1,"minorEdit":false,"hidden":false,"_links":{"self":"https://confluence.wdc.com/rest/experimental/content/525424594/version/1"},"_expandable":{"content":"/rest/api/content/525424594"}},"extensions":{"position":"none"},"_links":{"webui":"/display/CSSFW/Update+Status","edit":"/pages/resumedraft.action?draftId=525424594&draftShareId=0984750c-3696-4918-b9ce-4358fefc26c9","tinyui":"/x/0ldRHw","collection":"/rest/api/content","base":"https://confluence.ai.com","context":"","self":"https://confluence.ai.com/rest/api/content/525424594"},"_expandable":{"container":"/rest/api/space/CSSFW","metadata":"","operations":"","children":"/rest/api/content/525424594/child","restrictions":"/rest/api/content/525424594/restriction/byOperation","ancestors":"","body":"","descendants":"/rest/api/content/525424594/descendant"}}
```

Above is the output I get on chrome when this page is not updated. But I want to update its content i.e its storage.
I am guessing that the payload I am using right now is not in the right format. Any suggestions? Note: The link, username, and password shown here are all fictional.

Comment: I've never used this so I'm not sure but I'm guessing it's something to do with "allowedInReadOnlyMode" being true. Maybe you need to change permissions to allow edit. That would explain why you can "get" the page but can't "post" to it

Comment: Try to change `data=payload` to `json=payload`

Comment: @ShubhamPeriwal I don't think that's an issue. I went to the webpage itself and found out that anyone can view/edit this page.

Comment: @AndrejKesely My bad. I forgot to edit this file. I already tried this change and it gave me 400 response. If I do data=payload it shows response of 415 i.e content error which is fixed. I think the information format of my payload is wrong. I edited to json=payload in the question.

Comment: are you sure that put request needs that much detail? seems like a lot for put request. I found this link: https://developer.atlassian.com/server/confluence/confluence-rest-api-examples/#manipulating-content , and have less detail compared to your example. before debugging it through python easy attempt could be made by postman or any other plugin.

Comment: In link in @simpleApp comment I see example in `curl` and you could try to convert it to python on page https://curl.trillworks.com/ . But using Google I found module [Atlassian Python API](https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/) and maybe you should use it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're still stuck on this, based purely on your error message:

`"errors can't change an existing page's space."`

I would double check the space that you have identified it as being in. If you have just copied it directly from the Confluence examples then it has `"key":"TST"`, but your get request gives `"key":"AIENG"`. I had similar issues when trying to the same method and it was solely down to that, but equally I don't know if you have changed it on your example here just for display.

NB: `auth` also works without the `HTTPBasicAuth` (but I'm also very new to coding so it might be good practice!), and I've found `data=payload` tends to work better for me.

I'd also second the recommendation on the [atlassian-python-api](https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/) as it does make life a little easier.